# When $P\otimes_R M \to R \otimes_R M$ is injective for every (finitely generated) prime ideals $P$ of $R$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, flatness

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. If $M$ is an $R$-module such that for every finitely generated prime ideal $P$ of $R$, the map $i\otimes Id: P\otimes_R M \to R \otimes_R M\cong M$  is injective, then is $M$ a flat $R$-module ? If this is not true in general, then what if we assume the injectivity for all prime ideals ? Or assume $R$ to be Noetherian ?

I know that to show flat-ness, it would be enough to show injectiveness of $I\otimes_R M \to R \otimes_R M\cong M$ for every  finitely generated ideal $I$ of $R$, but I'm unable to see whether that is true here or not.

Comment: For Noetherian rings, this is standard. A module is flat if and only if $Tor^1(M,N)=0$ for all modules $N$, which you can reduce to the case of finitely generated modules first and then to all $R/P$, $P$ prime ideal next. This is what is implied by your assumption.

Comment: I see ... is there a more elementary proof of that without using the $Tor$ ? And what happens in the non-Noetherian case ?